# Write a unit test for a data binding property of Mat-button [color]

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jasmine, angular9, ts-jest

I am trying to write a unit test for a data-binding property of HTML element Mat-button.

Code is below:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
   <button data-testid="group-button" mat-raised-button *ngFor="let role of user.groups"

       [color]="role == 'ADMIN' ? 'warn' : 'primary'">{{role}}</button>
</div>
```

I need to write a unit test for [color] property to check color is primary when role is 'ADMIN'

I tried this so far using debug element:

I am mocking user.groups as `["ADMIN", "FOO", "BAR"]`

```
it('should change button color based on user groups', () => {
   const groups = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('[data-testid="group-button"]'));

   expect(groups[0].nativeElement.getProperty('color')).toBe('Primary'); // Fail
   expect(groups[0].nativeElement.getAttribute('color')).toBe('Primary'); // Fail

   //expect(groups[0].nativeElement.textContent).toBe('ADMIN')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution for my problem..

The color attribute is converted to ng-reflect-color in browser so test was not finding the attribute. The below test worked:

```
it('should change button color based on user groups', () => {
   const groups = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('[data-testid="group-button"]'));

   expect(groups[0].nativeElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-color')).toBe('warn'); // Pass

   expect(groups[1].nativeElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-color')).toBe('primary'); // Pass

}
```